# ExpandableListView start New Activity

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

I have problem when I want to start a new activity from a child 
in an ExpandableListView

#### My Code:

```
package com.multilayerexpandable;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ExpandableListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ExpandableListActivity implements
        OnChildClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ExpandableListView expandbleLis = getExpandableListView();
        expandbleLis.setDividerHeight(2);
        expandbleLis.setGroupIndicator(null);
        expandbleLis.setClickable(true);

        setGroupData();
        setChildGroupData();

        NewAdapter mNewAdapter = new NewAdapter(groupItem, childItem);
        mNewAdapter
                .setInflater(
                        (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE),
                        this);
        getExpandableListView().setAdapter(mNewAdapter);
        expandbleLis.setOnChildClickListener(this);
    }

    public void setGroupData() {
        groupItem.add("TechNology");
        groupItem.add("Mobile");
        groupItem.add("Manufacturer");
        groupItem.add("Extras");
    }

    ArrayList<String> groupItem = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Object> childItem = new ArrayList<Object>();

    public void setChildGroupData() {
        /**
         * Add Data For TecthNology
         */
        ArrayList<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("Java");
        child.add("Drupal");
        child.add(".Net Framework");
        child.add("PHP");
        childItem.add(child);

        /**
         * Add Data For Mobile
         */
        child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("Android");
        child.add("Window Mobile");
        child.add("iPHone");
        child.add("Blackberry");
        childItem.add(child);
        /**
         * Add Data For Manufacture
         */
        child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("HTC");
        child.add("Apple");
        child.add("Samsung");
        child.add("Nokia");
        childItem.add(child);
        /**
         * Add Data For Extras
         */
        child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("Contact Us");
        child.add("About Us");
        child.add("Location");
        child.add("Root Cause");
        childItem.add(child);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
            int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked On Child",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
}
```

#### The adapter

```
package com.multilayerexpandable;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class NewAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    public ArrayList<String> groupItem, tempChild;
    public ArrayList<Object> Childtem = new ArrayList<Object>();
    public LayoutInflater minflater;
    public Activity activity;

    public NewAdapter(ArrayList<String> grList, ArrayList<Object> childItem) {
        groupItem = grList;
        this.Childtem = childItem;
    }

    public void setInflater(LayoutInflater mInflater, Activity act) {
        this.minflater = mInflater;
        activity = act;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        tempChild = (ArrayList<String>) Childtem.get(groupPosition);
        TextView text = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = minflater.inflate(R.layout.childrow, null);
        }
        text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        text.setText(tempChild.get(childPosition));
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, tempChild.get(childPosition),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return ((ArrayList<String>) Childtem.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groupItem.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = minflater.inflate(R.layout.grouprow, null);
        }
        ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(groupItem.get(groupPosition));
        ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

The problem is how to start new activity when i clicked that child.
like HTC and start new HTC Activity.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you access to the specific child clicked and hence the position in your List of items.

The implementation could look something like this example:

```
 @Override
  public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked On Child"+childPosition,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // Go to child #0 specific class.
    Intent child0Intent = new Intent(this, Child0Activity.class);
    startActivity(child0Intent);
 }
return false;
}
```

A full example of how to implement it can be found [here:](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/10/android-expandablelistview-example.html)

Comment: How if i want to click each child, and each child show specific activity?

Child.add("HTC");
        child.add("Apple");
        child.add("Samsung");
        child.add("Nokia");

Answer (score 0):

```
expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                if(groupPosition==0){
                    if(childPosition == 0){
                        Intent child0Intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Child0Activity.class);
                        startActivity(child0Intent);}
                    if(childPosition == 1){
                        Intent child1Intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Child1Activity.class);
                        startActivity(child1Intent);}
                    if(childPosition == 2){
                        Intent child2Intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Child2Activity.class);
                        startActivity(child2Intent);}
                }
                if(groupPosition==1){
                    if(childPosition == 3){
                        Intent child3Intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Child3Activity.class);
                        startActivity(child3Intent);}
                    if(childPosition == 4){
                        Intent child4Intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Child4Activity.class);
                        startActivity(child4Intent);}
                    if(childPosition == 5){
                        Intent child5Intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Child5Activity.class);
                        startActivity(child5Intent);}
                }
                return false;
        }});
```

Answer (score 0):

in your setOnChildClickListener try

```
final String selected = (String) listAdapter.getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);
Intent intent;
            switch (selected){
                case "Capital Letter":
                    intent = new 
Intent("MainActivity.this, ActivityMain2.class");
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Intent intent  = null;
         switch (groupPosition){
                case 0:
                    switch (childPosition){
                        case 0:
                            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.slika1);
                            intent  = new Intent(activity, Activity1.class);
                            break;
                        ....
                    }
                    break;       
                case 1:
                    switch (childPosition){
                        case 0:
                            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.slika2);
                            intent  = new Intent(activity, Activity2.class);
                            break;
                        ....
                    }
                    break;
            }
         convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {    
                    activity.startActivity(intent);
                 }
          });
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.